# Distinction between processing and execution?

Tags: php, return

I ran into a note from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) (the last note). The one who left the note said:

> using return on a global scope it will end EXECUTION but NOT PROCESSING.

I don't know the exact meaning of "EXECUTION" and "PROCESSING" and the distinction between them.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that both those terms have been written by a user, and do not come from PHP manual itself, however same PHP Page answers your question:

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script
>   file is ended. If the current script file was included or required,
>   then control is passed back to the calling file. Furthermore, if the
>   current script file was included, then the value given to return will
>   be returned as the value of the include call. If return is called from
>   within the main script file, then script execution ends. If the
>   current script file was named by the auto_prepend_file or
>   auto_append_file configuration options in php.ini, then that script
>   file's execution is ended.

So even when Processing is finished on that current file with return, it will return control back to the file which included it (if it was). If it was not included anywhere then processing and execution both will stop there

Also one important comment on that very site explains

> Now, the way php works is before it executes actual code it does what
>   you call "processing" is really just a syntax check.  It does this
>   every time per-file that is included before executing that file.  This
>   is a GOOD feature, as it makes sure not to run any part of
>   non-functional code.  What your example might have also said... is
>   that in doing this syntax check it does not execute code, merely runs
>   through your file (or include) checking for syntax errors before
>   execution.  To show that, you should put the echo "b"; and echo "a";
>   at the start of each file.  This will show that "b" is echoed once,
>   and then "a" is echoed only once, because the first time it syntax
>   checked a.php, it was ok.  But the second time the syntax check failed
>   and thus it was not executed again and terminated execution of the
>   application due to a syntax error.

Reference for both Quotes : [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Comment: Actually,I've read all the notes before the post. It's only the last note that I cannt catch on.